# iMac IP address for remote access to server

Tags: ip

I need to provide IP address for iMac desktop for remote access to server;

could you please suggest which IP address should I provide?

```
Admins-iMac-3:~ 3052$ ifconfig | grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }'
192.168.12.14
(base) Admins-iMac-3:~ 3052$ curl -s http://ipecho.net/plain; echo
82.17.16.164
```

Comment: try 192.168.12.14 one